# Make terminal alias, to group video and audio setting changes, for using a/v receiver

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, pulseaudio, alias

Kubuntu 14.04 LTS (3.16.0-45-generic)- KDE - Pulse Audio volume control - System settings > display settings.

Current in/outputs and system setup.

1st HDMI output to main PC screen.

2nd HDMI output available to a/v sound system & projector screen (have to switch audio to a/v with pulse audio controller, add in projector with display settings, display setting has to be made to have the HDMI actually output anything to the receiver)

What I have to do now: Prepare media, open display settings, add display(projector), open pulse audio controller, switch to hdmi source, play media.

What I want to do:

Open Terminal, type in $(alias)

display added, sound switched

$(aliasstop)

2nd display taken off, sound switched back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would possibly write a short bash script to include both. You have to know your displays' and sinks' names prior to writing it.

To see your displays use `xrandr -q` command,
to find your sinks use `pacmd list-sinks` command

**The script**

```
#!/bin/bash

function changes {
xrandr --output yourpcdisplay --same-as 2nddisplayname
pacmd set-default-sink "sinkname"
}
#xrandr will now mirror your displays, I guess that was the idea
#pacmd will set your default output sink as you name it

function reset {
xrandr --output 2nddisplayname --off
pacmd set-default-sink "sinkname"
}
#this time xrandr will switch off the second display

while [ 1 ]
do
echo "1 - make changes"
echo "2 - reset"
read -n1 answ
case $answ in
1) changes
   break
   ;;
2) reset
   break
   ;;
*) echo "not an option"
   break
esac
done
```

Now as you run the script, pressing **1** will make the desired changes and **2** will reset them. Run the script with its path or add it to `$PATH` environment variable. It's possible to create aliases too.

Hope this was even close to the solution you wanted.

**NOTE** changing the output sink via command line may only take effect if stream target device reading is disabled. It can be done by editing the corresponding line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to:

```
load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false
```